# iOS Some UIImageView being stretched

Tags: ios, uiimageview, stretched

This seems like a silly question, but I have a `UITableView` and each row has a `UIImageView` with a dimension of `80x80`. The actual content of the image is either `80x80` or `80x64`. I recently added some new `80x64` images and the heights of those are being stretched whereas the old `80x64` images are not (they are simply centered within the `80x80` frame).

I vaguely remember setting some kine of xattr on my images a while back, but I can't seem to find what it was. Would this have something to do with my new images being stretched vertically?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You might want to look at the [`contentMode`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIView_Class/UIView/UIView.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UIView/contentMode) for your image view, specifically try `UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit`. I notice this, especially, when I set `image` properties for `UITableViewCell` cells asynchronously. But if I have the routine that is setting the `image` to also set the `contentMode`, and all is well.

Comment: Awesome, thanks Rob that worked. That was seriously driving me crazy!